# Pass hashtable with bundle in Java

Tags: java, android

I have a hashtable this is my code

```
class Message
{
    public String message, sender;
    public Message (String msg, String from)
    {
        message = msg;
        sender = from;
    }
    public String toString () { return sender+": "+message; }
}
```

I am defining my table with this code

```
Hashtable<String, List<Message>> table = new Hashtable<String, List<Message>>();
```

How can I pass this table variable with bundle ? Example I am passing string with this code

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", "test");
```

Now I want to pass `table.get("test")` this with bundle.

How can I do this ?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742374/android-make-this-object-as-parcelable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [Bundle#putSerializable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable))?

It should work if you add `implements Serializable` to your `Message` class, as `Hashtable` etc. are serializable.

Of course, for getting your Hashtable back from the bundle you'll have to cast it.

**Example**

```
Hashtable<String, List<Message>> originalTable = new Hashtable<String, List<Message>>();
// ... put some data into originalTable

// put originalTable into bundle    
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("table", originalTable);

// extract table from bundle
Hashtable<String, List<Message>> extractedTable = (Hashtable<String, List<Message>>)bundle.getSerializable("table");

// Now, extractedTable should contain same data as originalTable
```

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: I am getting this error: The method putSerializable(String, Serializable) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Message>)   I changed my class what is wrong ? http://prntscr.com/4bcxyu

Comment: Try replacing `List` with `ArrayList`.

Comment: It's fixed.But I have one more problem in fragment.I am traying to get values,but I can't. My code is giving error but I can't see any error.Can you check this what is wrong ? http://pastebin.com/piLiw9yA

Comment: What error does your code give? I did not get any compiler errors (after removing every lines with references to layouts etc).
You should, however, put the class Message into a separate file. If you have it directly within this class and (probably) in another class where you put the data into the bundle, you basically have 2 different classes which will cause the Serialization/Deserialization process to fail.

Comment: I don't understand what is the error.There is no information in compiler.But when I remove the class in fragment it is not giving error.I already defined this class in main activity.Is this a problem ?

Comment: Remove it from MainActivity too and instead put it into a separate class file (Message.java). This way, MainActivity and ConversationFragment both will use the _same_ class and not 2 different classes that just happen to have the same name.

Comment: When I try to reach list from fragment my app is crashing now logcat: http://prntscr.com/4bdhc5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59043/discussion-between-ridcully-and-tolgay-toklar).